# How to disable a input box using Id while add a new row in the table using clone method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function and HTML form which contains a table that has an `id` of `Phone` and there is a javascript function to add and delete rows.

My problem is while create a new row by add method I want the table data input field (`id="Employee_ID"`) I want to disable. Is it possible can someone help me.

```js
$("input.add").live('click', function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $clone.find("select").val('');
    $clone.find("a").removeAttr("href");
    $clone.find("label").val('');
    $clone.find(':checkbox:checked').prop('checked', false).val('N');
    $clone.find("#Employee_ID").prop("disable", true);
    $tr.after($clone);
});
```

Comment: Can you please add your HTML to the question. Also note that  `live` was deprecated a long time ago, and has been removed from the source in the latest versions of jQuery. Do you know which version you're using?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I want to say better to find the element with `class` name and `disable` it!! and when you `clone` it try to give a different Id for `cloned` element as `IDs` in DOM should be unique. Try to use `attr` instead of `prop` and finally it should have been `disabled` instead of `disable`.

```
$clone.find("#Employee_IDClass").attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work as expected because IDs must be unique per document. So when you say `$clone.find("#Employee_ID")`, the search isn't limited to the `$clone` element - instead if will find an arbitrary element with the ID `Employee_ID` somewhere on the page.

You need to avoid IDs for elements that you clone *or* you must assign new IDs for the clones.

If you want to try the former, you can assign a class to the `input` element or locate it by type (`$clone.find('input')`).